# How to know which package in `package.json` needs specific version of another required package?

Tags: nuxt.js, package.json

When running `npm run dev` with Nuxt, I'm getting a warning and a bunch of error:

```
WARN  webpack@5.65.0 is installed but ^4.46.0 is expected
```

Everithing get fixed after adding webpack to my package.json:

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^4.46.0",
  ...
}
```

However, how to know which package in `package.json` actually needs this specific version of webpack ? And why this package doesn't install such needed dependency ?

Comment: The simplest way to see package dependencies is to run `npm list --all`, it will print the dependency tree in the terminal. If you want something nicer looking and easier to browse and analyze, you can use [npm-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tromgy/npm-tree) (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Comment: I usually check the `yarn.lock` file for this. You do have 2 packages that are not compatible together. Since Nuxt2 is only available with Webpack4 and here you're using a package based on Webpack5.

Comment: @tromgy very useful and nice package!